# How to set control focus inside an MFC custom control

Tags: c++, mfc

Experts!

I am using a class that inherits `CWnd` to make the content visible using a horizontal scroll bar

The control I want to create looks like this:

[image]

However, I have some problems and leave a question

When the button receives focus, it changes to blue. If another button is pressed, the button that received the existing focus should be unfocused.

[image]

The button does not release focus as shown in the second picture.

However, the above problem occurs when implemented in Dialog, not in SDI.

I need help solving this problem.

## Custom Control Create Code;

```
m_ScrollWnd.Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, CRect(0, 0, 0, 0), this, 1234);

BOOL CScrollWnd::Create(DWORD dwStyle, CRect &rect, CWnd *pParent, UINT nID)
{
    dwStyle |= ((WS_HSCROLL) );

    return CWnd::Create(CScrollWnd::IID, nullptr, dwStyle, rect, pParent, nID);
}


m_Button3.Create(_T("Hello3"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON, CRect(0, 0, 0, 0), this, 1238);
```

Comment: Another issue is that the [`WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543(v=vs.85).aspx) flag is not used, so users won't be able to TAB into and out of the scroll window. Fix: `m_ScrollWnd.CreateEx(WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT, ...);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The so called "default button handling" is done by a function named `IsDialogMessage`.

The easiest way to control this is to make your parent control a window derived from `CDialog`, or if it's a view derive from `CFormView`. The MFC will handle all this for you in the appropriate `PreTranslateMessage` handler.

If you want to do this by your own you might insert your own `PreTranslateMessage` handler and use `IsDialogMessage`. The `CWnd` class also has a predefined implementation named `CWnd::PreTranslateInput`.

So this might be sufficient:

```
BOOL CYourParentClass::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    // allow standard processing
    if (__super::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg))
        return TRUE;
    return PreTranslateInput(pMsg);
}
```

Using `CFormView` / `CDialog` is the better way from my point of view, because also other "problematic things about dialogs" are solved in it. Including loosing and getting focus and activation...

Answer (score 0):

Official document from MSDN: [Dialog Box Keyboard Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/dlgbox-programming-considerations#dialog-box-keyboard-interface)

BTW, xMRi explains it very well.